# Entity Framework 5 Code First - add user permission as part of the seeding process

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am creating a EF Code First application, and I want the database to be used further on by reporting. Due to company policy, I need to do this via a network account.

So the question is - how do I grant [read] permission to a windows user to a database created by EF Code First?

Answer (score 4):

Script the grant permission sql and execute it in `Seed` method

```
    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        .....

        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("GRANT ....");
    }
```